What does こそとも mean?

部屋の中はうす暗く、こそとも音がしなかった。

I can't figure out the meaning of こそとも in the above sentence. Could there be something like ということ implied between うす暗く and こそ to mean "even though inside the room it was gloomy, there was no sound"?

こそ(と) here seems a variation of onomatopoeia こそり(と), which depicts faint sound in quiet environment (or noise made particularly when doing something secretly).
